# contributes to their extraordinary and thrilling immediacy

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the part in italics. What does immediacy mean here? I'd appreciate some clarification on it.

> A strain of intense female sexual fantasy and eroticism
> runs through the first four chapters of the novel and *contributes
> to their extraordinary and thrilling immediacy*. The
> scene in the red-room unmistakably echoes the flagellation
> ceremonies of Victorian pornography. As in whipping scenes in The Pearl and other underground Victorian erotica, the mise-en-scene is a remote chamber with a voluptuous decor, and the struggling victim is carried by female
> servants.
>
> [Elaine Showlater: A literature of their own, 1977](https://books.google.com/books?id=E5j7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=%22A%20strain%20of%20intense%20female%20sexual%20fantasy%20and%20eroticism%20runs%20through%20the%20first%20four%20chapters%20of%20the%20novel%20and%20contributes%20to%20their%20extraordinary%20and%20thrilling%20immediacy.%20The%20scene%20in%20the%20red-room%20unmistakably%20echoes%20the%20flagellation%20ceremonies%20of%20Victorian%20pornography.%22&source=bl&ots=BqnjYShwil&sig=ACfU3U0D26IygpvUQHAI-J1RVVbidbxoQg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil7pX9oMvtAhVUuXEKHczMAjsQ6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22A%20strain%20of%20intense%20female%20sexual%20fantasy%20and%20eroticism%20runs%20through%20the%20first%20four%20chapters%20of%20the%20novel%20and%20contributes%20to%20their%20extraordinary%20and%20thrilling%20immediacy.%20The%20scene%20in%20the%20red-room%20unmistakably%20echoes%20the%20flagellation%20ceremonies%20of%20Victorian%20pornography.%22&f=false)

Comment: '... makes them seem so real'.

Comment: I can't imagine that Charlotte Bronte had had any exposure to pornography!

Comment: A writer who gives you "immediacy" is giving you a powerful feeling *right now*.

Answer (score 2):

> A strain of intense female sexual fantasy and eroticism runs through the first four chapters of the novel and contributes to their extraordinary and thrilling immediacy.

A slight rephrasing, and the sentence might read—

> A strain of intense female sexual fantasy and eroticism runs through the first four chapters of the novel, and **this strain** *contributes to the extraordinary and thrilling immediacy of the first four chapters.*

As is apparent from the given excerpt, the writer is talking about some novel ( possibly of the Victorian era, and I am assuming it's some novel of Hardy's) that deals, *perhaps explicitly*, with sex. It's to be recalled that the Victorian era was marked by prudishness and placed a taboo on even risqué references, let alone go on to provide their descriptions. With subjects such as pornography, *immediacy* refers to the absence of any intervening media to tone down the erotic content the writer has put in. Thus the writer is talking about the novel's remarkable and blunt portrayal of pornography in an era in which it was highly tabooed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's talking about the novel Jane Eyre.

Answer (score 2):

> A strain of intense female sexual fantasy and eroticism runs through
> the first four chapters of the novel and contributes to their
> extraordinary and thrilling immediacy.

**Paraphrase**

A strain (of intense female sexual fantasy and eroticism) contributes to the extraordinary and thrilling immediacy of the first four chapters.

> **extraordinary** 
> 1a: going beyond what is usual, regular, or customary
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extraordinary
>
> **immediate** 
> b: being near at hand
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immediate

I would interpret "immediate" in this context as, "up close and personal" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/up-close-and-personal

(cross-posted with @user405662)